# DNA strings sorting function problem

Tags: c++

Well, I'm trying to solve the following problem, and almost done:
http://acm.pku.edu.cn/JudgeOnline/problem?id=1007

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
/*

int compare(size_type pos1, size_type n1,
const charT* s, size_type n2 = npos) const;*/
int * sort(string *w, int n, int l, int * count){

         for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
               for(int k= 0; k < l; k++){
                     for(int z = 0; z < k; z++)
                            if(w[k][z] > w[k][z]) count[i]++;
                     }
               }
        return count;
         }

int main(){

cout << "Enter the number of strings, followed by the length of each one: " << endl;
int n,l;
cin >> n >> l;
int *count = new int[n];
string *s = new string[n];
for(int i =0; i < n; i++){
cout << "Enter the string #" << i+1 << endl;
cin >> s[i];
}
int * x = sort(s, n, l, count);
for(int i = 0;  i < n; i++){
      cout << x[i]<< endl;
      }

 getchar(); getchar();

}
```

I've no problem but the if condition line in sort(), and the I can't get the value of **count** correctly from sort()

Update: I just want you to find a suitable form for the if condition using the string subscript like the one above.

Comment: is this homework of some sort?

Comment: No, it's not a homework of any sort

Answer (score 4):

```
if(w[k][z] > w[k][z])
```

You are comparing a number with itself.  This means count[i] will never be incremented.

I believe you want w[i][z]>w[i][k] instead. You should also initialize count to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "sortedness", i.e., from the definition in the mentioned page: the number of pairs out of order.

Functionally written that would be

```
unsortedness( {} ) = 0

unsortedness( a1, a2, ... an ) = 
    count( smaller_then( a1 ), {a2,a3,...,an} ) 
    + unsortedness( {a2,a3,...,an} )
```

If you can pour that in C++ syntax, you're done.  Hint: there is a standard function [`std::count_if( begin, end, comparator )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/), in which you can use [`std::bind2nd( std::less<char>(), a1 )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind2nd/) as comparator.

Answer (score 0):

First, you tagged your question, why don’t you use C++ features such as strings? Second, use `std::stable_sort` to perform the actual sorting for you. You need to supply a fitting sorting criterion to `stable_sort`. This is where your code comes in: as a criterion, you supply it with a function (functor) which compares the sortedness of a string, using your (corrected) function.

Comment: I wanna do it myself. Not, using std::stablesort

Comment: @Loai: fair enough. I thought the point was rather to implement the `sortedness` metric.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph No offense, but why everyone thinks that I should use built-in method to do things for me?. Shouldn't I learn how to do it myself?

Comment: @Loai: because that’s how code is written? After all, you opted to use C++ in favour of say, assembly. You use `cin` and `cout`. Why did you do this? Shouldn’t you learn how to do it yourself? So you *are* definitely using built-in methods. I thought the puzzle was about implementing the count of inversions, not about sorting (which is trivial, and well-known).

Comment: My objective is to solve the problem myself, not using a built-in method for that problem. Yes, I can use cin or cout, because my objective isn't creating a I/O method.